# type useState setter in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, types

I am trying to pass a `useState` setter to a child component, but unsure how to type this.

```
const Parent = () => {
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
   return(
     Child count={count} setCount={setCount} />
   );
}
```

Then in the `Child` component I am trying to type the setter but I am seeing the following error.

> Type 'Dispatch< SetStateAction< string[] > >'is not assignable to type '() => void'.

My code looks like this

```
type Props = {
  count: number;
  // the issue is the line below
  setCount: () => void;
}

const Child = ({ count, setCount }: Props) => {
    .... code here
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can specify that the `setCount` prop function expects a number as first argument and the error will go away.

```
type Props = {
  count: number;
  setCount: (num: number) => void;
}
```

Comment: I would love to know how to type it the way react does. Because you cant just pass a number to the original setter, you can also pass a function to modify the state using the previous state

Answer (score 12):

```
const Parent = () => {
   const [myState, setMyState] = useState<YourType>({});
   return(
     <Child count={myState} setCount={setMyState} />
   );
}
```

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'

type Props = {
  count: YourType;
  setCount: Dispatch<SetStateAction<YourType>>;
}

const Child = ({ count, setCount }: Props) => {
  // works with
  setCount(newState)

  // also with
  setCount(oldState => {
    // ...
    return newState
  })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The type of your react useState setter is `Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>` where `T` is the type of your property. You could translate this as dispatching a 'set-state' action.
So taking the Props type from your example, it would look like this:

```js
type Props = {
  count: number;
  setCount: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>
}
```

Type definitions: [source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L1775)